# Dynamically importing a module upon submitting a form in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dynamic-import

A have an 'Add to basket' button which submits a form via Ajax with all products' details. At the moment the module responsible for that operation is loaded straight away when the website is loaded. I would like it to be loaded only when the button is clicked, though. This is what I have so far:

```
$('form:not(.contact-form__items)').on('submit', event => {
  import('./modules/adding-products-to-basket.js')
  .then(module => {
    module.AddingProductsToBasket.addProductToBasket(event);
  });
});
```

Module's content:

```
export const AddingProductsToBasket = {

  addProductToBasket (event) {
    const _this = AddingProductsToBasket;
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
      url: 'basket',
      method: 'POST',
      data: $(event.currentTarget).serialize(),
      dataType: 'text',
      success: function(response) {
        _this.openAddedToBasketLightbox();
        }
      },
    });
  }

};
```

I'm not getting any errors in the console but the problem is that
`event.preventDefault()` inside `addProductToBasket` doesn't do it's job, so user is taken to the basket page instead of staying on the page where the 'Add to basket' button is.

Comment: Yes, you must do the `event.preventDefault()` immediately in your handler, you cannot do that asynchronously.

Comment: Btw, I would suggest loading the module that handles the form events as soon as the form is shown, not when it is submitted.

Comment: There is no downside loading the submit handler immediately with the form. You can put it in its own file to load it async but are these couple hundred bytes worth the effort?

Comment: I guess you are right, probably not worth it.

Comment: @Bergi If you post your comment as an answer, I'm happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you both for your help. It's working now.

Loading the module when the form shows:

```
if ($('form:not(.contact-form__items)').length) {
  import('./modules/adding-products-to-basket.js')
  .then(module => {
    $('form:not(.contact-form__items)').on('submit', event => {
      module.AddingProductsToBasket.addProductToBasket(event);
    });
  });
}
```

Loading the module not when the form loads but when it is submitted:
(`event.preventDefault()` in `AddingProductsToBasket()` can be removed)

```
$('form:not(.contact-form__items)').on('submit', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  import('./modules/adding-products-to-basket.js')
  .then((module) => {
    module.AddingProductsToBasket.addProductToBasket(event);
  });
});
```